# TestRail integration with Pace Automation Framework

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

Does PAF supports TestRail integration of automation scripts?
TestRail is the single source of truth for all testing data.
If yes, Please provide a brief introduction to establish the integration.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** . PAF supports integration with Testrail.

- Following config.properties entries needs to be configured to connect TestRail and upload, execute scripts in TestRail through PAF.  
  TEST_SYSTEM=testrail  
  HOST= 
  USERNAME= 
  PASSWORD= 
  PROJECT= 
  PWD_ENCRYPTED=true 
  TEST_FOLDER_ID= 
  REMOVE_XML_FROM_STEP=true 
  TEST_SET_NAME=
- To encrypt the password, use eclipse configuration “Encrypt Password” and Update PASSWORD= in config.properties file.